# Haskell function that executes each action until a predicate returns True

Tags: haskell

The following function executes each action from the list until a predicate returns `True`. I have a feeling that this function can be rewritten using `fold` and without the `do` construct but I don't know how.

```
execUntil :: (Eq a, Monad m) => [m a] -> (a -> Bool) -> m ()
execUntil [] p = return ()
execUntil (a:as) p = do
    r <- a
    if p r then return () else execUntil as p
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a question that fits more into stackoverflow. Your code works.. but you're asking how to do a specific thing.

Comment: I'm kind of asking for advice on how to improve my code that works. Isn't a code review about it?

Comment: That's why I'm not sure

Comment: Since `foldM` is a left fold, I don't think you can use it for this. You also can't use a non-monadic fold. `execUntil` is called `whileM` in `Control.Monad.Extra` and `Control.Monad.Loops`, implemented with `when` rather than `if/then/else` but otherwise the same. It will still do recursion under the hood but there's no way around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not totally sure what you're looking for, but maybe something like this?

```hs
import Control.Monad (void)
import Data.Bool (bool)

execUntil :: Monad m => [m a] -> (a -> Bool) -> m ()
execUntil = flip $ \p -> void . foldl (\ma mb -> ma >>= bool (p <$> mb) (pure True)) (pure False)
```

I wouldn't recommend it, though. `foldl` doesn't have any way to short-circuit, so this implementation will traverse the entire `[m a]`, even beyond when the `a -> Bool` predicate is satisfied.

IMO, the code you've provided is totally fine as-is! Except perhaps for the unnecessary `Eq a` constraint ;p